# Запрость данные с помощью aiohttp HTTP2/0

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Необходимо сделать асинхронный запрос http версии 2.0. В обычной версии Session от requests можно приделать адаптер http20, а вот прикрутить адаптер к aiohttp не получается. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека httpx поддерживает асинхронный http 2/0